# Facebook Post dialog activity not taking full screen

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm currently using the SDK 5.0.3 beta and Im not able to get the dialog and popups to show on fullscreen. They always have the notification space missing.

I tried changing the theme in the androidManifest without any luck....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 1463221990566431" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is a screenshot of how it is displayed.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17531095/Screenshot_2014-02-16-13-19-07.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is due to facebook's use of this theme:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

From doing some research, it seems translucent activities can't override the no title bar behavior of the activity underneath it.

If you change this theme to `Theme.Translucent` under the facebook login activities in `AndroidManifest`, you can see the issue goes away for the facebook sign in dialog (the notifications bar takes up the empty room at the top).

However I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue for the post to wall scenario, as none of the activities seem to be getting picked up.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is finally recognized by FB team at least. But the fix will be in next 7.0.X (beta) of Facebook SDK.
There was no official suggestion on how to workaround this issue in 6.2.2 yet.

Forum discussion:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/need-help-from-an-android-facebook-expert.330838/

Bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/794128344019396/

Comment: Sidenote: I'm on FB SDK 6.2.2, perhaps I will work around this by blackout my entire screen when calling this API so that at least it has uniform black background.